# QGIS LTR geolocate raster

Tags: raster, mac, geolocation, qgis-3

I've a raster from Google Maps satellite view, also three visible geolocated points (not the corners) in UTM 18N (Garmin). Sorry, I'm blown away with the details in the 3.28 user manual. What please is the direct way to enter a georeference for a selected visible point on the raster?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the georrefencer tool built-in qgis. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3ot_qYN3Zw
You can add the points, now the question is, how can you know where the points are located in your image, well, I recommend first loading the points, and then loading the XYZ layer from google satellite, you are able to (at least) realize where are you points located within the target image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK, I found how to get Georeferencer to open, I've imported a raster image and geolocated 3 points according to the directions. How do I get QGIS to use it? I tried clicking connect georeferencer to qgis and the reverse; nothing happened. When I go to the QGIS project, there has been no georeferencing that I can see - points added to a vector layer can't be seen...
How do I persuade QGIS to use the georeferenced data that georeferencer itself has no problem finding?

Comment: it seems a problem with QGIS. May you reinstall it? I strongly recommend the last LTR version

Comment: Paul, that's what I've got. Never used it before; used 1.8 a decade ago on a PC. After over 60 years with computers, I'm not used to an app that makes me feel dumb, but sad to say QGIS 3.28 (LTR) does...